# Gravação de áudio e reprodução online

Tags: php, javascript

Bom, não tenho nenhuma noção em fazer isso, queria té que alguém me falasse com qual linguagem eu poderia realizar, que estarei me aprofundando mais. Então, queria que após um usuário clica em um botão, e o mesmo já ter permitido o site em usar seu microfone, que ele gravasse um áudio, e após isso, o áudio hospedasse na host. Como posso realizar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer isso com javascript. Ve [isto](https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder), e um bom lugar onde podes começar. E [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101037/record-audio-using-the-users-microphone-with-html5) esta uma implementação com PHP para upload o file.

Comment: Valeu campeão! Irei tentar aqui!